# find and update data of a certain user's nested data in MongoDB Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database of users and their info of the places they checked. Each time an user clicks on a particular place, I want to check in the data base if he hasn't yet clicked on that place. User's schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   email: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'Įveskite el. paštą'],
       unique: true,
       lowercase : true,
       validate: [isEmail, 'Įveskite tinkamą el. paštą']
   },
   password: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'Įveskite slaptažodį'],
       minlength: [6, 'Minimalus simbolių skaičius – 6']
   },
   placeinfo: [
       {
       title: String,
       score: String
       }
   ]
});
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

If I search for a place title, it searches in all database for all users, but I want it to search for a particular user, for example testuser@test.com and if he has "Kalnaberžės piliakalnis" in his placeInfo array.

```
{
  _id: 60d2eecea704c60a705ef3fb,
  email: 'testuser@test.com',
  password: '$2a$10$PN3krKgwsdtQV1Y/Z.wQ7eeJbQ9GIrOEjHcpGlYCQR33Oxub5bJ4a',
  placeinfo: [
    { _id: 60d2eefba704c60a705ef3fe, title: 'Kalnaberžės piliakalnis' },
    { _id: 60d2ef10ea1c3437a4e47c31, title: 'Pakalniškių piliakalnis' },
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "email": "testuser@test.com",
      "placeinfo.title": "Kalnaberžės piliakalnis"
    }
  }
])
```

Or basicly `find`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "email": "testuser@test.com",
  "placeinfo.title": "Kalnaberžės piliakalnis"
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ztbpe3_5ByV)